# Sorting values with condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sort the col2 in descending order based on col1. I have the feeling that the answer is very simple, but I can't find a correct way. I would appreciate a lot some help.

The dataframe looks like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 
AB   5    Blue
AB   1    Red
AB   2    Green
AC   1    Red
AC   4    Blue
AD   9    Red
AD   5    Blue
AD   7    Green
```

The desired output:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 
 AB   5    Blue
 AB   2    Green
 AB   1    Red
 AC   4    Blue
 AC   1    Red
 AD   9    Red
 AD   7    Green
 AD   5    Blue
```

What I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.sort_values(['Col1','Col2'], ascending = False)
```

```
df.groupby(['Col1'])['Col2'].sort_values(ascending = False)
```

None of the above methods gives the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
print(df.sort_values(['Col1', 'Col2'], ascending=[True, False]))
```

**Output**

```
  Col1  Col2   Col3
0   AB     5   Blue
2   AB     2  Green
1   AB     1    Red
4   AC     4   Blue
3   AC     1    Red
5   AD     9    Red
7   AD     7  Green
6   AD     5   Blue
```

From the documentation on [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

> ascending : bool or list of bool, default True
>
> ```
> Sort ascending vs. descending. Specify list for multiple sort orders. If this is a list of bools, must match the length of the by.
> ```